# setInterval increment index mystery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am bangging my head against a wall, I cant figure out what is happening when I try increment my index value from outside my function.

So I starts off as 0, great! Each loop through i gets i +1 (this all seems great) ... but when I click #sliderNext you will see I dont add to the i value, yet it still increments the i value (why???) That means when I click prev I have to decrease the value by 2 instead of i-- (again, why?) ... am I being thick and not seeing something obvious?

Perhaps a better way to add prev + next (one that does not stop the setinterval completely)

```
$.when( loadImages() ).done(function(a1){

    var i = 0;
    var numberOfImgs = imgArr.length;

    function sliderRotate(passi){           
            $('#autoSlider').html(imgArr[i]); //show with current i index
            i++;    //it should increment AFTER image has shown 

            if (i >= numberOfImgs || i < 0){ i = 0; }
    } 


sliderRotate();
intervalID = setInterval(sliderRotate, 3000);

//prev + next clicks
            $('#sliderNext').on( 'click' , function(){              

                    clearTimeout(intervalID); 
                    //x = i + 1;    
                    sliderRotate();         
            }); 
            $('#sliderPrev').on( 'click' , function(){ 

                    clearTimeout(intervalID);   
                    if ( i === 0 ){ i = imgArr.length -2; } //this only kind of works if I click twice on the first image
                    else{i = i - 2; } 
                    sliderRotate();                 
            }); 


});// end of when
```

Here is a snippet example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var imgArr = [
  '<img src="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg">',
  '<img src="http://assets.barcroftmedia.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/assets/images/recent-images-11.jpg">',
  '<img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/pia20645_main.jpg?itok=dLn7SngD">',
  '<img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/pia18368-1041.jpg?itok=Fkc2j_kw">',
  '<img src="http://www.irishtimes.com/polopoly_fs/1.2527148.1454955520!/image/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/landscape_685/image.jpg">',
  '<img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/US/Feb2016/video-481880130.jpg">'
];

var i = 0;
    var numberOfImgs = imgArr.length;

    function sliderRotate(passi){        
      $('#autoSlider').html(imgArr[i]);
      i++; //should increment here, not before???     
      
      if (i >= numberOfImgs || i < 0){ i = 0; }
    } 

   
sliderRotate();
intervalID = setInterval(sliderRotate, 3000);

//prev + next clicks
      $('#sliderNext').on( 'click' , function(){        
              
        clearTimeout(intervalID); 
        //x = i + 1;   
        sliderRotate();  
      }); 
      $('#sliderPrev').on( 'click' , function(){ 
        
        clearTimeout(intervalID);   
        if ( i === 0 ){ i = imgArr.length -2; } //kindah works, but still buggy
        else{i = i - 2; } 
        sliderRotate();     
      }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sliderContainer">
<div id="sliderNext">Next</div><br><br><br>
<div id="sliderPrev">Prev</div>
<div id="autoSlider"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Initial value of `i` is `0`. `sliderRotate` function renders the first image (at index `0`) and increments `i` by `1`. In the next execution of this function the second image (at index `1`) will be shown and `i` will have a value `2`.

Now, you want to get back to the previous image (at index `0`). But value of `i` is `2`. You have to show image at index `i - 2`.

Comment: Gosh, I was being dense... I need a coffee. Thank you so much for your patience. Any Idea on how to restart the set interval counter rather than clearing it when click?

Comment: @Sony ThePony you're very welcome. If you want to restart the interval you just need to clear the interval and set it again. After call to the `clearInterval` add this line `intervalID = setInterval(sliderRotate, 3000);` to restart it.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling sliderRotate():

```
$('#sliderNext').on( 'click' , function(){              

                clearTimeout(intervalID); 
                //x = i + 1;    
                **sliderRotate();**         
        });
```

And that will increment it by 1:

```
function sliderRotate(passi){           
        $('#autoSlider').html(imgArr[i]);
        i++; //should increment here, not before???     

        if (i >= numberOfImgs || i < 0){ i = 0; }
}
```

Same for "prev", you are adding 1 when you call sliderRotate(), that is why you need to subtract 2.

Here is a working example with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/owbL084z/2/

Comment: Holy cow, I was going to write back with why it still didnt make sense and it suddenly clicked!! Gosh, I was being dense... I need a coffee. Thank you so much for your patience. Any Idea on how to restart the set interval counter rather than clearing it when click?

Comment: Here is a full working example were it will iterate correctly, as well as restart the interval after the same 3 seconds. Basically place the interval in a function, and call it when you want to restart it, but only after clearing the previous one: https://jsfiddle.net/owbL084z/2/

Comment: Does that jsfiddle help you out?